# Something wrong when I try to draw a triangle with opengl and glew using glsl

Tags: c, macos, opengl, glsl

I'm using OpenGL 3 and Glew in order to draw a triangle, I have a window (changing the background color works fine) but I can't put my shader on it. I did some tests like:

`glGetProgramiv(shader_programme, GL_LINK_STATUS, &isLinked);`

`printf("\nProg : %i",isLinked);`

And it's fine; print returns 1 for the program, the vertex and the frag.

I suppose I missed a clear somewhere, but I'm not sure and also pretty lost here...

This is my code:

```
#include    "../include/scop.h"
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include ".../lfw3/3.2.1/include/GLFW/glfw3.h"


t_scop      *ft_init_window(t_scop *scop, t_parse parse)
{
if (!glfwInit())
    ft_putstr("error init");
else
{
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
WIN = glfwCreateWindow(WIN_X, WIN_Y, "Scop", NULL, NULL);
glfwMakeContextCurrent(WIN);

glfwSetInputMode(WIN, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);
glfwSetInputMode(WIN, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
glfwPollEvents();
glfwSetCursorPos(WIN, WIN_X / 2.0, WIN_Y / 2.0);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
}

    float points[] = {
  -1.0f,  -1.0f,  0.0f,
  1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
  0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f
    };

//init buffer and fill it
    GLuint vbo = 0;
    glGenBuffers (1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9 * sizeof (float), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//init VertexArray
    GLuint vao = 0;
    glGenVertexArraysAPPLE (1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE (vao);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray (0);
    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer (0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

const char* vertex_shader =
  "#version 330 core\n"
  "layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
"void main () {"
"gl_Position.xyz = position;"
"gl_Position.w = 1.0;"
  "}\0";

const char* fragment_shader =
  "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec3 color;"
"void main () {"
"color = vec3(1,0,0);"
"}\0";
//create vertex
GLuint vs = glCreateShader (GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource (vs, 1, &vertex_shader, NULL);
glCompileShader (vs);
//tests
GLint success = 0;
glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
printf ("Taille du source:%i\n", success);
if (GL_FALSE == success)
printf("false");
else printf("true");

//create frag
GLuint fs = glCreateShader (GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource (fs, 1, &fragment_shader, NULL);
glCompileShader (fs);
//tests
success = 0;
glGetShaderiv(fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
printf("Taille fs : %i",success);

// GLuint shader_programme = LoadShaders (vs,fs);
GLint shader_programme = glCreateProgram ();
glAttachShader (shader_programme, vs);
glAttachShader (shader_programme, fs);
glLinkProgram (shader_programme);
//tests
GLint isLinked = 0;
glGetProgramiv(shader_programme, GL_LINK_STATUS, &isLinked);
printf("\nProg : %i",isLinked);

//idk if i need to do this now
glDetachShader(shader_programme, vs);
glDetachShader(shader_programme, fs);
glDeleteShader(vs);
glDeleteShader(fs);
glGetError();

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(WIN))
{

  glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glClearDepth(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  glUseProgram (shader_programme);
  glBindVertexArrayAPPLE (vao);
  glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  //glUseProgram(0); ???
  glfwPollEvents ();
  glBindVertexArrayAPPLE (0);
  glfwSwapBuffers(WIN);
}

//  glfwTerminate();

return (scop);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in this line:

```
glClearDepth(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

`glClearDepth` ([doc](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glClearDepth.xhtml)) specifies with which value the depth buffer should be cleared and expects a floating point value between 0 and 1. It is the similar to `glClearColor`, just for depth.

Additionally, you should be using the core profile VAO functions instead of the ones from the APPLE extension. The apple extension should only be used in a OpenGL context <= 2.1.

Comment: hey thx for your answer, according to the doc i think the `glClearDepth` is not necessary cause i have `glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` which clear color and Depth. 
I tried anyway to change the value of `glclearDepth` but it did nothing, there is something wrong elsewhere.
And i can't use the core profile VAO functions i have compil errors i did.